# How can i run KSQL stream with compression

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am using **KSQL** for processing Kafka data. I can able to create persistent kafka streams, but the output topic for this stream is not compressed one. How can i define the compression type while creating the steream.

```
CREATE STREAM TARGET_TOPIC WITH **(COMPRESSION='SNAPPY')** AS SELECT * FROM SOURCE PARTITION BY ID
```

I am expecting giving compression configuration like above but the above syntax is not correct. If compression is possible in ksql please assist on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1. You can use the `SET` command in KSQL to set the producer config that controls compression *before* creating the stream, e.g.

```sql
SET 'compression.type'='snappy';
CREATE STREAM TARGET_TOPIC WITH **(COMPRESSION='SNAPPY')** AS SELECT * FROM SOURCE PARTITION BY ID
```

2. or you can set it in the ksql-server.properties file if you want ALL output to be compressed.